# Configuring multer to upload files to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express

The express Router is setup as such:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var multer  = require('multer');

var uploading = multer({
  dest: './uploads/',
  limits: {fileSize: 1000000, files:1},
});
router.post('/upload', uploading.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
  console.log('success'); 
});
 module.exports = router;
```

I am attempting to upload files:

```
curl -F "image=@/Users/runtimeZero/Desktop/nassau.jpg" localhost:3000/auth/upload
```

The express server throws the below error:

```
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (/Users/.../node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/../node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
    ...
    ...
    at HeaderParser.push (/Users/.../node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (/Users/.../node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
```

From multer documents this seems pretty straight forward. However, not so much when actually using it. What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`multer` readme](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) you will see that `multer()` returns an object that contains various functions that return different middleware, depending on your needs.

For example, to accept a single file whose `name` is 'avatar':

```
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads/'});
router.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
  console.log('success'); 
});
```

Comment: Now that you've added more info to your question, the problem now is that you're referencing the wrong field name. You're using 'image' but looking for 'avatar'. Change that and it should work fine.